# .Net7 ExchangeService send mails from linux-based containers

Tags: c#, linux, docker, exchange-server, .net-7.0

I got an .Net7 console-application running in a docker-container.
This application should send mails using the ExchangeService:

```
    //preparing ExchangeService
    _exchangeService = new ExchangeService()
    {
        Url = new Uri("https://my.domain/ews/Exchange.asmx"),
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        AcceptGzipEncoding = true,
    };
    _exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(mailUser, mailPassword); //credentials are required
    _exchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    _exchangeService.PreAuthenticate = false;
    //overwriting headers
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{mailUser}:{mailPassword}");
    var headerValue = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    _exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Add("Authorization", headerValue);

    //Sending mail
    EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(_exchangeService)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, body)
    };

    message.ToRecipients.AddRange(recipients);
    message.Send()
```

As soon as I run this codesnippet within an linux based container (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0) the I'm getting the following excpetion:

> The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

The thing is, as soon as this code runs on windows it works like a charm.

I found some a [GitHub-entry](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/96) telling me to use Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard instead of Microsoft.Exchange.Webservice. But that doenst fix the error.

Also overwriting the auth-header, as it can be seen in the code snippet above, doenst change the result.

Thanks for some answers and ideas in advance.